# How can i change the size of the icon connected to the JButton

Tags: java, image, jframe, icons, jbutton

When you connect icon to JButton
( button.setIcon(icon); )
you get very small icon, How can I change the size of this icon?

My code:
(In this code you need to drag 1 file to the frame and look how small the icon)

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(){
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            for (DataFlavor flavor : support.getDataFlavors()) {
                if (flavor.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            if (!this.canImport(support))
                return false;
            java.util.List<File> files;
            try {
                files = (List<File>) support.getTransferable()
                        .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                return false;
            }

            for (File file: files) {
                String name = file.getName();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);

                JButton button = new JButton(name);
                button.setIcon(icon);
                panel.add(button);
                p.add(panel);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

In my expectation i want the option to change the size of the icon (I need the icon on the button)

I tried to get the img of the file (didn't work):

```
 Image img = ImageIO.read(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: 1) Don't use the updateComponentTreeUI(...) method. That is used internally in Swing when you change the Look and Feel. Instead you use the `revalidate()` method on the panel after adding the component. 2) You could use the `Image.getScaledInstance()` method on the image of the Icon, but that will cause pixelation of the image.

Comment: How can i transfer the Icon to Image

Comment: Read the `ImageIcon` for the method to get the image.

Comment: can you give me an example?
EDIT:
 (getSystemIcon -  return Icon not ImageIcon)

Comment: `ImageIcon icoe = (ImageIcon)` `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);`

`icoe.getImage().getScaledInstance(icoe.getIconWidth()*4,icoe.getIconHeight()*4,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); `

`button.setIcon(icoe);`

doesn't change the size of the image

Comment: Read the API is always the first step to solve a problem. The `Image.getScaledInstance()`. method returns a new Image. It has no idea that you added the image to the ImageIcon. So, you need to create a new `ImageIcon` with this image. Then  you set the Icon of the button.with the newly created ImageIcon. Also, regarding my first comment, the `revalidate()` statement is executed outside the loop, AFTER all button have been added to the panel.

Comment: `ImageIcon icoe = (ImageIcon)`
`FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);`
`icoe.getImage().getScaledInstance(icoe.getIconWidth()*4,icoe.getIconHeight()*4,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);`
`button.setIcon(icoe);` doesn't change the size of the image

Comment: 1) Why are you repeating the same comment? I already explained why the code doesn't work. What part of my explanation do you not understand? I explicitly stated you need to create a new ImageIcon. Where is your code that creates a new ImageIcon with the scaled image? Or, if you want to update your current Icon, then read the ImageIcon API for the method to use. 2) Post code with your question so it is readable, not with the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *simple program* which allows you to control the size of the icon using your scroll wheel.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Main {

    File file = new File("path-to-your-file.png");
    Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
    int size = 100;

    public Main() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel();

        jl.setIcon(icon);
        jf.addMouseWheelListener(e -> {
            
            size -= e.getWheelRotation();
            
            Image image = ((ImageIcon) icon).getImage().getScaledInstance(size, size, Image.SCALE_FAST);
            
            jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            
        });
        
        jf.add(jl);
        
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }

}
```

### Here's how you can achieve this in your program

**Step 1:** Save the default icon in a new variable. We'll use `icon` as an example.
**Step 2:** When you want to resize the image, add an `ImageIcon` cast to your `icon` as shown in the program above. Make sure you have `(ImageIcon) icon` within brackets, else this will cast the final output to ImageIcon
**Step 3:** Use `Image#getScaledInstance` to scale the image you get from the ImageIcon.
**Step 4:** Finally change the JLabel icon to a new ImageIcon, with the image you had gotten from the previous step.

I hope this helps :)